# Confluence Condition statement / macro display

Tags: macros, confluence

Using "Insert JIRA Issue/Filter' macro in confluence, is there way to make a conditional statement on a confluence page stating, if issues = 0 do not display macro?

No I'm not an admin (was in my previous life...where i would have simply created a custom macro).

Comment: If HTML macro is enabled, you could hide other macro's output using Javascript...

Comment: It isn't enabled.  It's heavily locked down.